# Undefined reference to while linking dll library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linker-errors

I am trying to compile one of the metatrader 4 c++ api libraries in code::blocks.
Here is the main program

```
`#include "stdio.h"
 #include "MT4APITest.h"
 int main(void)
 {
  char err[255];
  SunkTCPClient* pCl = MT4_TC_StartClient("127.0.0.1", 4567, err);
  MT4APITest test;
  test.Run(pCl);
  return 0;
 }`
```

In build options -> liker settings, I have included relative path "bin/Debug/MT4_API.lib"

In build options -> Search Directories -> Compiler - >, I have included "C:\home\mt4\". This is the folder where I have kept my mt4_API.dll library. In the same folder, I've placed below files.

```
`main.cpp
MT4_API.h
MT4_APITest.cpp
MT4_APITest.h
mt43.cbp (for code blocks).`
```

When I compile this, the compilation command turns out to be

`mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\mt43.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\MT4APITest.o    bin\Debug\MT4_API.lib`

and getting the error

`C:/cygwin/home/LENOVO/mt4/mt43/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to MT4_TC_StartClient(char const*, int, char*, wchar_t const*)@16'
obj\Debug\MT4APITest.o: In function ZN10MT4APITest15TestAccountInfoEv':
C:/cygwin/home/LENOVO/mt4/mt43/MT4APITest.cpp:48: undefined reference to MT4_TC_GetAccountInfo(SunkTCPClient*, MT4AccountInfo*)@8'
C:/cygwin/home/LENOVO/mt4/mt43/MT4APITest.cpp:48: undefined reference to MT4_TC_GetErrorDescription(MT4_RET_CODE)@4'
obj\Debug\MT4APITest.o: In function ZN10MT4APITest14TestSymbolInfoEv':
C:/cygwin/home/LENOVO/mt4/mt43/MT4APITest.cpp:57: undefined reference to MT4_TC_GetSymbolListCount(SunkTCPClient*, int*)@8`

and the list continues. May I know what I am missing here.

[image]

Comment: it seems you have placed the bin/Debug/MT4_API.lib to the wrong side of that linker settings tab. The one on the right is for additional options, not for additional libraries. Either put it as additional library or use -l:bin\Debug\MT4_API.lib as additional option.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get that. I've included screenshot of my linker settings. Should I change something there.

Comment: ok. not sure what exactly is the problem, the compile command you are showing looks strange to me, but could be mingw accepts it like this. perhaps try to remove the library with relative path and add it with absolute path, just to see if it helps.

Comment: I suppose MT4_APITest.h is including MT4_API.h, right?

Comment: I've tried that too. But same error. May i know how a typical compilation command should look like when we have to link 'lib' file and its path

Comment: Yes, thats correct. MT4_API.h is included in MT4_APITest.h

Comment: usually you would say -lLIBNAME or -l:FIILE_WITH_LIB instead of including the file as an additional argument

Comment: mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\mt43.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\MT4APITest.o -l:bin\Debug\MT4_API.lib

Comment: Okay. Now, i've tried creating console application in code::blocks. Hence that -l options is not coming. I tried building a new project choosing "dynamic link library" instead of "console application". At that time, when i link libraries, it comes up with -l option. May i know if I should build dynamic link library project or console application project. Sorry, I am new to windows.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are doing, but it seems you are building a console application that will use a ready DLL that you already got from somewhere. Thus your project type will be console application and you need to specify that it should use the library. Yes, trying to compile from command line first can help resolve it. what output does the above compile statement with "-l:..." option produce when run from command prompt?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to create console application that uses external DLL library. When i ran with command prompt, i get new error `g++ -o bin/Debug/mt43.exe obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/MT4APITest.o bin/Debug/MT4_API.lib main.cpp`   `/usr/include/w32api/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:100:2: warning: #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.      This can cause runtime problems with W32 sockets" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types. Definitions.h:103:20: fatal error: tchar.h: No such file or directory  #include <tchar.h>`

Comment: First of all, when compiling, do not mix object files .o together with source files .cpp in the same command (main.o vs. main.cpp). Second, when you want to link with some library, I suggest you use the -l option, do not add it to the command line directly. You can try to rename the MT4_API.lib to libMT4_API.lib and use the "-lMT4_API" option. What output you get. You can zip your whole project, upload it somewhere and post a link to that zip so that we can try to see where is the issue.